# Regex not working properly in Javascript code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex, textbox

I have a JavaScript function that fires successfully on the onkeypress/onkeyup event for an asp.net textbox control as follows:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtboxLatestTag" runat="server" onkeypress="validate()" onkeyup="validate()"></asp:TextBox>

function validate() {
  var str = $("#txtboxLatestTag").val();
  var pattern = /^\d{1,2}[.]\d{1,2}[.]\d{1,2}[.]\d{1,2}/gm

  if (!str.match(pattern)) 
  {
   document.getElementById("txtboxLatestTag").style.color = "red";
  }
else 
{
   document.getElementById("txtboxLatestTag").style.color = "white";
}
```

The regex is supposed to match entries in the format of:
10.10.10.10 or
1.1.1.1
or anything allowing 1 to 2 digits between each "." character.
This works, however the problem is that it ALSO matches with 
1.1.1.100 i.e. it should not allow 3 numbers at the end of the string, only 2.
This works perfectly in regexr.com but I cannot figure out why it is matching on this.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure there's something wrong? I tried your code using jsfiddle and it worked fine even for the `1.1.1.100` case.

Comment: Hi Rax I don't want it to work for 1.1.1.100. I have marked answer below. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want to do to exclude extra characters at the end of the string is add in the end of input character `$` (or end-of-line character, since you're using multiline mode). This will cause extra characters at the end to invalidate the match. For example:

```js
var oldPattern = /^\d{1,2}[.]\d{1,2}[.]\d{1,2}[.]\d{1,2}/gm;
console.log("Old pattern match:");
console.log("10.10.10.100".match(oldPattern));

var pattern = /^\d{1,2}[.]\d{1,2}[.]\d{1,2}[.]\d{1,2}$/gm;
console.log("New pattern match:");
console.log("10.10.10.100".match(pattern));
console.log("10.10.10.1".match(pattern));
```